# Advanced mathematics search tool

Tags: support, search, search-engine, math-se

Last year there was an advanced search website for Stack Exchange mathematics (maybe for other sites, I don't know) where you could input part of a formula, and it would list all Stack Exchange answers/questions with that formula. It was very useful and seems to have disappeared. Is it gone forever?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you mean [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/)? If that's so, it is not gone.

Comment: yes that was what I meant, I couldn't find it. Thanks!

Comment: @Jess I will just add that this search engine is mentioned in the FAQ-proposed post on the local meta: [How to search on this site?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29265) A separate post specifically about Approach0 is here: [Announcing a third-party search engine for Math StackExchange.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/24978)